# React Native how to upload multiple photos to server at once

Tags: react-native

I've tried to upload multiple images to server at a once by using **fetch**.

Here is my code chip.

```
 chooseImage(){
  ImagePicker.openPicker({
    multiple: true,
    waitAnimationEnd: false
  }).then(images => {
    var photos = []
    images.map((image, i) => {
      photos.push({
        uri:image.path,
        name: image.name,
        type: 'image/jpg'
      })
      let source = {uri: image.path}
      this.state.photos.push({image: source, check: true, hairstyle: '', price: ''})
    })
    var data = new FormData();

    data.append('photos', photos)

    const config = {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept':'application/json',
        'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;',
        'Authorization': this.props.auth.token
      },
      body: data,
    }

    fetch("http://**.***.***.***/api/providers/uploadPhotos", config)
    .then(res=>res.json()).then((res) => {
      console.log("----------Response----------")
      console.log(res)
      this._getStylist()
      this.setState({photo_take: false});
    }).catch(err=>{
      console.log("------------Error-----------")
      console.log(err)
      console.log("error in uploading image")
    }).done()

  }).catch(e => {
    console.log(e);
  });
}
```

When I try it, I get 200 response from server and photos doesn't upload to server actually.
I searched the solution a few days, but couldn't find the suitable solution.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

I am new at react native but seems like you can loop throght images array to upload images Maybe you can add this post actions in promise array then you can be sure that every photo added to your storage. I use promise array methods while working on my node js server project its very useful.

Edit for example:

```
var photos=[];
var promise_array=[];
photos.forEach(function(photo){
const config = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Accept':'application/json',
    'Content-Type':'multipart/form-data;',
    'Authorization': this.props.auth.token
  },
  body: photo,
}

promise_array.push(fetch("http://**.***.***.***/api/providers/uploadPhotos", config)
.then(res=>res.json()).then((res) => {
  console.log("----------Response----------")
  console.log(res)
  this._getStylist()
  this.setState({photo_take: false});
}).catch(err=>{
  console.log("------------Error-----------")
  console.log(err)
  console.log("error in uploading image")
}).done())

})

Promise.all(promise_array);
```

Since fetch is a promise I can put in promise array. Maybe there is syntax error in example and I am not sure react native support promise methods fully but here is documentation for promise method I use https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: could you possibly provide me one example ?

Comment: it will trigger a performance error. See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50423018/upload-multiple-photos-error-one-of-the-sources-for-assign-has-an-enumerable-ke